# What is the query to find emp details whose names contain letter vowel?(oracle database)

Tags: oracle

```
Emp Table
---------------
empid     ename       sal        hiredate
101       ashish      5000       23-jul-2016
102       ankith      20000      21-sep-2012
103       uma         3000       10-jan-2004
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use REGEXP_LIKE

```
select * from my_table 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (ename, '([aeiou])');
```

ignore case

```
select * from my_table 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (ename, '([aeiou])', 'i');
```